# Redirection of output in infinetely running python script

Tags: python

I have a python script which has a `while(1)` condition , takes input from a table in database
processes it and writes something to `stdout` but I am unable to redirect its output to a file.I tried all standard methods and found maybe because the script never stops and I have to
stop it with `Ctrl-Z` it is unbale to append the ouput of `stdout` to file.

Any clues??

Comment: This sounds like an issue with buffering -- can you post your output code here?

Comment: @Livius Its a big code , it includes several other codes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that it never writes a newline?  If that's true, you need to `sys.stdout.flush()` occasionally.

Comment: By default, output is buffered in memory until a newline is written.  `sys.stdout.flush()` flushes the buffered output to the disk, even if there are no newlines.

Comment: sys.stdout.flush() works correctly, but putting print "\n" instead does not work ? also does this flusshing takes too much time ?? How often can I do it ??

Comment: If printing a newline doesn't work, that's odd.  As for the cost of flushing, there are many factors.  Your best bet is to test it.  Try not to do it for every character. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also disable I/O buffering with the `-u` option: `python -u yourscript.py`. (This can diminish performance in some cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    completeName = os.path.abspath("**Path name of the file**")
    f = file(completeName, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    print "Whatever you want to put into file"
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout
    f.close()
```

Comment: Could you explain why you think this would make a difference?

Comment: @RichieHindle I'm guessing the idea is to circumvent the whole issue with redirecting `stdout` at the command line and instead do it in the script. This has other issues, of course, not the least of which is that Python will still buffer file I/O.